# User signup feathers-authentication with passport-facebook-token

Tags: node.js, passport.js, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, passport-facebook-token

I am trying to allow users to sign up for my service via "login with facebook".

[image: Mobile app user signup via facebook login]

I have already done arrow 1-2. I need to do arrows 3-6. I have made a minimal Feathersjs example at https://github.com/morenoh149/feathers-chat-facebook-signup-api

I seem to be having trouble getting feathers-authentication and passport-facebook-token to generate the User object and sign them up. I've reviewed passport-facebook-token carefully. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474900/630752) explains that in the callback to passport-facebook-token you should create the User object. How do I do this with feathers-authentication?

When I provide the token in the body

```
curl localhost:3030/authentication \
  --data-binary '{\
    "strategy": "facebook-token", \
    "access_token": "<phone token>" \
  }'
```

I get

```
{"name":"NotAuthenticated",
"message":"You should provide access_token","code":401,
"className":"not-authenticated",
"data":{"message":"You should provide access_token"}
```

when I pass the token as a header

```
curl localhost:3030/authentication \
  -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>"
```

I get error

```
{"name":"GeneralError",
"message":"Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined",
"code":500,"className":"general-error","data":{},"errors":{}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded and ran the repo, I used VSCode to run the app and set break points. I created a breakpoint in the before create hooks on users.

The issue here is that the gravatar hook is expected the email to be `context.data` but it is in fact embedded within the facebook response. You will need to look at extracting the email from that data so that you can create a gravatar or just remove the gravatar hook altogether.

Comment: I commented out the body of the gravitar hook and the user object does get created

Comment: I edited the repo to detail everything needed to make fb signup work. It shows how to read the email from facebook so gravitar works https://github.com/morenoh149/feathers-chat-facebook-signup-api