# How to use PassportJS with JWT in a REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, oauth, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm currently working on building a REST API where users can authenticate themselves via different passport strategies (`google`, `facebook`). The authentication has to be done without a session.

Now I've already worked on the local strategy and that works like so;
application `POST /login` to API and then when the user entered the right credentials they will get some payload back like so

```
[
    {
        "tokenType": "refresh",
        "expiresIn": 604800000,
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTUsImlhdCI6MTY0MDc4NzA4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQxMzkxODgwfQ.zdxdpX8NkiSTsbZj0xOd18RdbLjeSsQpkikLGW71xrE"
    },
    {
        "tokenType": "access",
        "expiresIn": 7200000,
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTUsImlhdCI6MTY0MDc4NzA4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQwNzk0MjgwfQ.EBDuJqQYT-D0bnYbC76_khe6b29c80R4pMyEaBNKLKE"
    }
]
```

However, the problem with the `google` and `facebook` strategy is that they work via `OAuth`. I'm struggling to find a way to send the above information (like with my local strategy) to the client after the OAuth authentication has succeeded.

These OAuth services work with a return URL like `/auth/facebook/return`. But this return URL is on the API which then can't send the information over to the client (or can it?).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `passport-facebook-token` that is altogether a different strategy from `passport-facebook`. It does provide the token that can be used to authenticate users.

```
passport.use('facebook-token', new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID        : "your-client-id",
    clientSecret    : "secret"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // console.log(profile);

     var user = {
        'email': profile.emails[0].value,
        'name' : profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName,
        'id'   : profile.id,
        'token': accessToken
    }

    // You can perform any necessary actions with your user at this point,
    // e.g. internal verification against a users table,
    // creating new user entries, etc.

    return done(null, user); // the user object we just made gets passed to the route's controller as `req.user`
  }
));
```

Use passport.authenticate(), specifying the 'facebook-token' strategy, to authenticate requests. You need to use it as middleware for any route to authenticate.

```
app.post('/auth/facebook/token',
  passport.authenticate('facebook-token'),
  function (req, res) {
    // do something with req.user
    res.send(req.user? 200 : 401);
  }
);
```

I would suggest you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929092/passport-js-passport-facebook-token-strategy-login-through-js-sdk-and-then-aut) link and the [code](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token#readme) under the hood that is well documented.